# Apache Storm Fields Grouping Calculation

Tags: apache-storm

I asked this question in the Storm user group and haven't gotten a response yet, so I decided to ask it here. I've found the code, and many references to how the the taskIndex is calculated but when I try using the following I don't get the same result as my Storm topology. I've also seen more than one posting where others report the same.

Here's the question:

Hello,

I’ve tried to use the information below to generate the hash, mod it, and in turn, calculate the correct consuming destination task index, but without success. I’ve scoured the Internet to find an example of a hand calculation of this nature and have turned up empty. I must be missing something in my hand calc, so I’m hoping someone on the list can help me out.

I have field grouped as follows:

```
    .fieldsGrouping(EXAMPLE_BOLT, EXAMPLE_BOLT_STREAM, new    Fields(TopologyConstants.EXAMPLE_FIELD_GROUPING_ID))
```

My EXAMPLE_BOLT emits as shown here:

```
    collector.emit(TopologyConstants.EXAMPLE_BOLT_STREAM, new Values(EXAMPLE_FIELD_GROUPING_ID_VALUE, EXAMPLE_DATA_INSTANCE));
```

I perform the calculation as follows:

```
    int numberOfConsumingTasks = x;
    Integer EXAMPLE_FIELD_GROUPING_ID_VALUE = y;
    ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
    alist.add(EXAMPLE_FIELD_GROUPING_ID_VALUE);
    int hashCode = Arrays.deepHashCode(alist.toArray());
    int targetTaskIndex = Math.abs(hashCode) % numberOfConsumingTasks;
```

The resulting targetTaskIndex value from this calculation does not match the value produced by Storm, when I use real values from my topology.
Can someone tell me what I’m doing wrong?
Thanks,

Aubrey

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using Storm 1.0.1.